# Timed out waiting for tasks to complete when stop Redistributor

Tags: jboss, jms, hornetq

I got a bunch of warning shows

```
09:56:11,069 WARN  [org.hornetq.core.server.cluster.impl.Redistributor] (Thread-5 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=98ea621a-fdd7-11e3-9e48-33de940622fd-752268326)) Timed out waiting for tasks to complete
09:56:11,092 WARN  [org.hornetq.core.server.cluster.impl.Redistributor] (Thread-12 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=98ea621a-fdd7-11e3-9e48-33de940622fd-752268326)) Timed out waiting for tasks to complete
09:56:11,108 WARN  [org.hornetq.core.server.cluster.impl.Redistributor] (Thread-2 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=98ea621a-fdd7-11e3-9e48-33de940622fd-752268326)) Timed out waiting for tasks to complete
```

There is only some monitoring jobs running at the same time.

The environment is jboss-eap-6.0 and hornetq 2.2.16 which is configured as multicast.

The stacktrace shows

```
at org.hornetq.core.server.cluster.impl.Redistributor.stop(Redistributor.java:107)
at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.QueueImpl.cancelRedistributor(QueueImpl.java:673)
at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.QueueImpl$2.run(QueueImpl.java:521)
at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:104)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

The source code of Redistributor shows

```
public synchronized void stop() throws Exception {
    active = false;
    Future future = new Future();
    executor.execute(future);
    boolean ok = future.await(100000);
    if (!ok) Redistributor.log.war("Timed out wating for tasks to complete");
}
```

The source code of Future shows

```
public synchronized void run() {
    done = true;
    notify();
}
```

Any idea why this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bug and I'm currently looking for a test replicating this issue.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/HORNETQ-1167

Comment: Thank you, will this bug cause some leak or something bad?